# How can I identify if a binary file is set-user-ID?

Tags: linux, binary, setuid

In Linux, how can I identify if a binary file is set-user-ID?

Can I use `ls -l`?

Comment: What is the problem with `ls -l`?

Comment: @michas I meant `using ls -l?`

Comment: Sure you can use `ls -l`, why the doubt?

Comment: @michas I was not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

executing `ls -l` you will get something like:

```
-rwSr--r--   1 user user    8111573 Sep 26  2012 net-snmp.tar
```

where the `S` (can be also `s`) indicates that this file has the SUID bit set

`S` is set when you do not have execution flag set

`s` is set when you have execution flag set

Comment: In short: `s` = `x` + setuid, `S` = setuid without `x`. (setuid+x gets the more "normal" character because it's more common)

Answer (score 5):

Either manually look at the file with `ls -l filename`, or from a script you can use

```
[ -u filename ] && echo SUID-bit is set
```

See also `man bash`:

```
   -u file
          True  if  file  exists  and its set-user-id bit is set.
```

See also `info ls`:

```
 The file mode bits listed are similar to symbolic mode
 specifications (*note Symbolic Modes::).  But ‘ls’ combines
 multiple bits into the third character of each set of permissions
 as follows:

 ‘s’
      If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit and the corresponding
      executable bit are both set.

 ‘S’
      If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit is set but the
      corresponding executable bit is not set.
```